# Body's background image covers part of header's background image in mobile version

Tags: css, mobile, header, background-image

This is my first attempt to make a webpage but something seems to go wrong with the mobile version of my page. On desktop everything is ok but on mobile, the right part of my header's background img is covered by the main background image.It is a little difficult to describe it so I 'm sending you the link for your better understanding http://rockittest.blogspot.gr/. 
I tried to resize the images, to change position, I've read all relevant threads but I couldn't fix it. Do you have any ideas about what can be wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To be honest i don't even get the problem. For me the website does not have a real mobiel version, there is not much happening when i resize it and somehow i only see 1 background.

Comment: Do you see only one background even in the desktop version?